# How can I append multiple files in HDFS to a single file in HDFS without the help of local file system?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am learning hadoop. I came across a problem now. I ran the mapreduce job and output was stored in multiple files but not as single file. I want to append all of them into a single file in hdfs. I know about **appendToFile** and **getmerge** commands. But they work only for either `local file system to hdfs`or `hdfs to local system` but not from  `HDFS to HDFS`. Is there any way to append the output files in HDFS to a single file in HDFS without touching local file system?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this would be to force your mapreduce code to use one reducer, for example, by sorting all the results by a single key.

However, this defeats the purpose of having a distributed filesystem and multiple processors. All Hadoop jobs should be able to read a directory of files, not isolated to process a single file

If you need a single file to download from HDFS, then you should use getmerge

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this directly in HDFS. But the below trick works. Although not a feasible solution, but should work if output is not huge.

hadoop fs -cat source_folder_path/* | hadoop fs -put target_filename

Comment: That will collect all files locally, still